# -print printing out string via npm but actually evaluating through powershell

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, package.json, npm-scripts

The following script is defined in my package.json:

```
    "abc": "node -p 'p=require(\"./package\");p.main=\"lib\";p.scripts=p.devDependencies=undefined;JSON.stringify(p,null,2)'",
```

If I run 'npm run-script abc' I end up with a package.json with the string

> 'p=require(\"./package\");p.main=\"lib\";p.scripts=p.devDependencies=undefined;JSON.stringify(p,null,2)'

If I run the command:

```
node -p 'p=require(\"./package\");p.main=\"lib\";p.scripts=p.devDependencies=undefined;JSON.stringify(p,null,2)'
```

Directly in powershell I actually get the json output I'm looking for.

Not sure why the difference? I tried using -e/-eval as well to no avail, it seems to think that it just prints out the script?

Answer (score 2):

Change your npm script to the following instead:

```json
"abc": "node -p \"p=require('./package');p.main='lib';p.scripts=p.devDependencies=undefined;JSON.stringify(p,null,2)\"",
```

Your npm script will now run succesfully via *Powershell*, *Command Prompt (cmd.exe)*, *Linux*, and *MacOS*.

**Changes are as follows:**

- The node/js code has been wrapped in JSON escaped double quotes `\"...\"` instead of single quotes.
- The actual node/js code itself utilizes single quotes `'...'` instead of JSON escaped double quotes `\"...\"` because using escaped double quotes in JavaScript is invalid syntax.

```
"abc": "node -p \"p=require('./package');p.main='lib';p.scripts=p.devDependencies=undefined;JSON.stringify(p,null,2)\"",
                ^^          ^         ^         ^   ^                                                               ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a quoting issue.

The problem is that running `npm run-script abc` is not interpreted in `powershell` (which properly supports both single and double quotes), but in `cmd`.

You can either:

Replace single quotes with double quotes, and use proper escaping (although the result may be a bit ugly):

```
"abc": "node -p \"p=require(\\\"./package\\\");p.main=\\\"lib\\\";p.scripts=p.devDependencies=undefined;JSON.stringify(p,null,2)\""
```

Use single quotes inside the javascript code and double qoutes to surround the script

```
"abc": "node -p \"p=require('./package');p.main='lib';p.scripts=p.devDependencies=undefined;JSON.stringify(p,null,2)\""
```